# TypeORM ManyToMany based on array of ids

Tags: many-to-many, nestjs, typeorm

i am building a project on NestJs using TypeORM and can not achieve to join tables using ManyToMany decorator and based on array of ids

here below what i tried and can not make it to work

In entity Courses i have a column name directionIds that i save array of ids, now i am trying to get a list of Directions based on directionIds availables

**my entities**

```
@Entity()
export class Courses {
  @ApiProperty()
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string

  @ApiProperty()
  @Column({type: 'character varying', name: 'name'})
  name: string

  @ApiProperty()
  @Column({type: 'uuid', name: 'direction_ids'})
  directionIds: string[]

  @ApiProperty({ type: () => Directions })
  @ManyToMany(() => Directions)
  @JoinTable()
  directions: Directions[]
}

@Entity()
export class Directions {
  @ApiProperty()
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string

  @ApiProperty()
  @Column({type: 'character varying', name: 'name'})
  name: string

  @ManyToMany(type => Courses, courses => courses.directions)
  courses: Courses[];
}
```

**i am calling the relation this way**

```
await this.repository.find({
  relations: ['directions']
})
```

**i end up everytime in**

```
relation "courses_directions_directions" does not exist
```

I have tried to specify different attributes to JoinTable as well i tried to specify RelationId to column directionIds, the error is same relation ... does not exist

Will appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you do like this and check once,
```@ApiProperty({ type: () => Directions })
  @ManyToMany(() => Directions, (direction) => direction.courses)
  @JoinTable()
  directions: Directions[]
```

I hope this will not give error, and if please share the error.

Comment: @BhargavGohil same error ->  relation "courses_directions_directions" does not exist

Comment: change the name of the JoinedTable once, IG that might be an issue

Comment: @BhargavGohil with what to change?

Comment: ```@JoinColumn({ name : "courses_directions_relation" })``` change to this.

Comment: @BhargavGohil again error -> relation "courses_directions_relation" does not exist

Comment: I am not sure why its throwing an error, but replace to this for last one, 
`@ManyToMany(() => Directions, (directions) => directions.courses, {  cascade: true,
    eager: true 
})
  @JoinTable({ name : "courses_directions_relation", 
    joinColumn: {
      name: 'courses_id',
      referencedColumnName: 'id',
    },
    inverseJoinColumn: {
      name: 'direction_id',
      referencedColumnName: 'id',
    }, })
  directions: Directions[]`

and can you check if typeorm made the a table `courses_directions_relation` ?

Comment: @BhargavGohil still same error, no the table is not created in postgress

Comment: Okay, so this is sure that the issue is not from this part of code. Something else has a break.